# qperf C github https://github.com/rbruenig/qperf

Tags: c, networking, cmake

I cloned iperf code on GitHub( github https://github.com/rbruenig/qperf), but I compiled it according to the content in readme and made an error. The error is as follows:

```
CMake Error at extern/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

  ./qperf/extern/quicly

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at extern/CMakeLists.txt:12 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "quicly" which is not built
  by this project.
```

Comment: Does the repository reference any [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/pl/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)? Did you remember to fetch them as well?

Comment: Indeed it seems like you did not follow the instructions regarding the git clone: `git clone --recurse-submodules git@github.com:rbruenig/qperf.git` clones the repo including submodules. You can get the submodules for the existing repo by using `git submodule update -- init --recursive`